# Prove that $\leq_p\subseteq\mathbb N^\infty\times\mathbb N^\infty$ is transitive.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am learning a programming learning and there while learning semantics I came across this question.

> Let $\mathbb N^\infty$ be the set of all infinite sequences of natural numbers (e.g., $[0,0,2,2,4,4,\dotsc]\in\mathbb N^\infty$) and let $\leq_p\subseteq\mathbb N^\infty\times\mathbb N^\infty$ be the relation that compares infinite sequences of natural numbers by their *prefix sums*. The $n$th prefix sum $p_n(s)$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ of a sequence $s\in\mathbb N^\infty$ is the sum of the first $n$ elements of $s$. We have $s\leq_p s'$  if and only if $s = s'$ or there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $p_n(s)<p_n(s')$ and $p_m(s) = p_m(s')$ for all $m\in \{0,\dotsc, n-1\}$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\leq_p$ is transitive.
> 2. Give an example for an infinite chain in $(\mathbb N^\infty, \leq_p)$.

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUJky.png)

It will be great, if someone explain me how to prove this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can simplify the description of $\leq_p$ a bit. Namely, $s \leq_p s'$ iff $s = s'$ or at the first index $n$ where they are different, we have $s_n < s'_n$. No need to do partial sums, we can just look at each individual element.

Let $x, y, z$ be three sequences so that $x \leq_p y$ and $y \leq_p z$. If $x = y$ or $y = z$, then we clearly have $x \leq_p z$, so let's assume that $x \neq y$ and $y \neq z$. Then ther is an index $n$ indicating the first place where $x$ and $y$ differ, and an index $m$ indicating the first place where $y$ and $z$ differ.

We have $x_i = y_i$ fo rall $i < n$ and $x_n < y_n$. Similarily, we have $y_j = z_j$ for all $j < m$ and $y_m<z_m$. There are now three cases.

- $n = m$. In this case, $x_i = z_i$ for all $i < n$ and $x_n < y_n <z_n$, so $x\leq_p z$.
- $n < m$. In this case, $x_i = z_i$ for all $i < n$, and for index $n$, we have $x_n < y_n = z_n$, so $x \leq_p z$.
- $n > m$. In this case, we have $x_j = z_j$ for all $j < m$, and for index $m$ we have $x_m = y_m < z_m$, so $x \leq_p z$.

This shows that $\leq_p$ is transitive.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I want to ask, what that index refers to. lets say n, is it for x or y.

Comment: and what will be the example of chain, if you have any

Comment: The index $n$ is the first index where $x_n\neq y_n$. Similarly, $m$ is the first index where $y_m\neq z_m$. They are relevant because if $x\neq y$ and $y\neq z$, then that index is the single index that $\leq_p$ cares about.  The simplest ascending chain would be $x_k=(k,k,k,\ldots)$.

Comment: Thank you again, i got this one. Can you explain this term a bit more : We have xi=yi for all i<n and xn<yn. (3rd para start). when i <n they are equal but on n x < y. is it because of the assumption that we made that they are different on n?

Comment: More or less, except the assumptions happened the other way around. We made the assumption that the sequences are different, and defined $n$ to be the first index where that happens.